# register infinispan cache listener in wildfly

Tags: infinispan, wildfly-11

I have a infinispan cache defined in wildfly `stanadlone.xml` as shown below.

```
    <cache-container name="dummycache" default-cache="stringCache">
        <local-cache name="stringCache">
            <expiration lifespan="1800000"/>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
```

This cache is initialized by the infinispan running embedded in wildfly itself. I could lookup and use the cache like below.

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:comp/env/infinispan/stringCache")
private Cache<String, String> stringCache;
```

Now I would like to add `listeners` to get notified about the `cache expired` events. But the question is how do I register this listener to the `infinispan cache` which is completely managed by `widlfly container`?

I find that we can `addListeners()` to cache object but at what moment ? Ideally I want it be initialized when the wildfly creates the cache itself. It looks the `infinspan-standalone` schema does not support `listener` element to set it in the cache configuration. So the only other way is to `inject` the cache in `filter` or similar and call `addListener()` then?

Is there any neat way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

To set the scene - I am running a web app on wildfly 10, which is run in standalone mode. The cache-container config in standalone.xml is:

```html
<cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
    <local-cache name="passivation">
       <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
       <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="BATCH"/>
       <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
    </local-cache>
    <local-cache name="persistent">
       <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
       <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="BATCH"/>
       <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
   </local-cache>
</cache-container>
```

Here are my changes step by step:

1. Dependency to infinispan

I have added

```html
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
 <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
 <version>9.2.4.Final</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

2. web.xml

Add a resource (in my case I am trying to get the resource for the cache container web)

```html
<resource-ref>
 <res-ref-name>infinispan/cacheContainer</res-ref-name>
 <lookup-name>java:jboss/infinispan/container/web</lookup-name>
</resource-ref>
```

I also added a servlet context listener because I want to add the cache listener on contextInitialized

```html
<listener>
 <listener-class>some.package.ContextListenerCacheAddListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

3. jboss-deployment-structure.xml

I have added this to my WEB-INF directory of the war

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.infinispan" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Turns out that if you skip this - infinispan classes will be loaded by different class loaders (as far as I can understand)

4. Java code

Injecting the resource and using it to add listeners to caches

```html
public class ContextListenerCacheAddListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Resource(name = "infinispan/cacheContainer")
    CacheContainer cacheContainer;

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ContextListenerCacheAddListener.class);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
            cacheContainer.getCache("myapp.war").addListener(new MyListener("myapp.war"));
            cacheContainer.getCache("passivation").addListener(new MyListener("passivation"));
            cacheContainer.getCache("persistent").addListener(new MyListener("persistent"));
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

    }

    @Listener
    public static class MyListener{

        private String name;

        public MyListener(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @CacheEntryCreated
        public void onCreate(CacheEntryEvent event){
            logger.warn(name +" created entry "+event.getKey() );
        }

        @CacheEntryModified
        public void onModify(CacheEntryEvent event){
            logger.warn(name +" modified entry "+event.getKey());
        }

        @CacheEntryVisited
        public void onVisited(CacheEntryEvent event){
            logger.warn(name +" visited entry "+event.getKey());
        }

        @TransactionRegistered
        public void onTransactionRegistered(TransactionRegisteredEvent event){
            logger.warn(name +" registered transaction entry ");
        }

        @TransactionCompleted
        public void onTransactionCompleted(TransactionCompletedEvent event){
            logger.warn(name +" completed transaction entry ");
        }
    }
}
```

My changes are just for testing and debugging purposes to solve a different problem than yours.

Comment: Thanks. I got it done using CDI @PostConstruct so it will add listener to injected cache when the service CDI bean is created.